# Android: ListView shows only last item saved by Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, list, file, listview

To make it clear , ma.getData() returns a string from another activity that i want to save in shared preferences. So every time i send a string(from an other activity) to the following activity i save it using the saveData()(this function is called when a button is clicked).. so i have a lot of strings to display in the listview using two more functions(loadData() and updateViews()).**These functions are called when activity starts , so to load in the listview the saved strings.**

The problem is that only the last string that i get from the other activity is displayed in the listView.

What i am doing wrong?

```
public class activity_profile extends AppCompatActivity {

MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
private static ArrayList<String> addArray;
ListView show;


private Button btn;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
public static final String TEXT = "text";


private String text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    mEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hist) ;
    show = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    namefield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    namelabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namelabel);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Update_btn);
    loadData();
    updateViews();
}
public void saveData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString(TEXT, ma.getData());


    editor.apply();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    text = sharedPreferences.getString(TEXT, "");

}

public void updateViews() {

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Collections.singletonList(text));
    show.setAdapter(adapter);
    //mEditText.setText(sb.toString());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

and this is my xml for the list view

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="398dp"
    android:layout_height="204dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/RecipeHistoryLabel">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_width="386dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwritting your data on a single key inside SharedPrefs.
Your options are:

1. Using a format to save and read data in shared preferences e.g. json
2. Use database e.g. Room

Example from (1) option.

```
//saving new data on previus key
//Use - to sepete data e.g. (FirstData-SecondData-ThiredData)
String yourNewData = "data";
String oldDataFromPrefs = prefs.getString("KEY");
String dataToBeSaved = oldDataFromPrefs + "-" + yourNewData;

//reading data as String[] to show it on the ListView 
//You need to pass tokens to your adapter
String readDataFromPref = prefs.getString("KEY");
String[] tokens = readDataFromPref.split("-");
```